# How to make Windows PE section that is mapped on request

Tags: windows, loader, portable-executable

I have a Windows module (driver) that has embedded a big chunk of raw binary data. This makes the module size quite big, thus increases the load time of the driver. 
Is it possible to put this binary data into a PE section that gets skipped by the loader when the module is originally loaded, so I explicitly load it later when there is a need for it? The aim is to decrease the loading time of the module. Thank you

Comment: Can you not store this binary data in a separate file and just load it when you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put data after end of PE image, and then open the file and read it.